# SharePoint 2013 favicon points to http://<site url>/favicon.ico

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, master-page, sharepoint-on-prem

When cache is empty the favicon is point to `http://site url/favicon.ico` and ask for username and password for intranet site. finally 404 file not fount.

After re-fresh it works properly and loads the favicon from masterPage.

In master page I am using

```
<SharePoint:SPShortcutIcon runat="server" IconUrl="/_catalogs/masterpage/favicon.ico" />
```

similarly, for CSS files, it shows `401 unauthorized` when cache is empty. After reload it works properly.

Thanks in advance for help.